# How to connect either one or two IP's/Ports on a socket

Tags: java, android

I'm currently running a socket that allows connection between a mobile application and the raspberry pi. But at the moment I want to make a dedicated button that lets u connect to the IP and Port of the RPi instantly instead of manually writing them down.

Snips of Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView speedTextField, distanceTextField;
ImageButton buttonDown, buttonUp, buttonLeft, buttonRight, buttonSpeedUp, buttonSensorDown;
WebView webView;
String SERVERIP = loginScreen.serverIp;
int SERVERPORT = loginScreen.serverPort;

String SERVERIP2 = "196.168.43.85";
int SERVERPORT2 = 50000;
```

Socket:

```
    class ClientAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            //Create a client socket and define internet address and the port of the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);
            //Get the input stream of the client socket
            InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            //Get the output stream of the client socket
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            //Write data to the output stream of the client socket
            System.out.println(text);
            out.println(text);
            System.out.println(text);
            text = "";
            System.out.println(text);

            //Buffer the data coming from the input stream
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            //Read data in the input buffer
            result = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Exception";
        }
        return result;

    }
```

loginscreen with instant button:

```
public class loginScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textResponse;
EditText address, port;
Button buttonConnect, buttonClear, buttonTapToConnect;


public static String serverIp;
public static int serverPort;
public static String serverIp2;
public static int serverPort2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginscreen);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.address);
    port = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.port);
    buttonConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    buttonTapToConnect = findViewById(R.id.TapToConnect);
    buttonClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
    textResponse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.response);


    buttonTapToConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //once clicked connect to IP and Port written in main activity class.
            //Change activities once clicked.

            startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connecting to Raspberry Pi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
    });
```

What I'm wondering at the moment is if the socket is able to check both IP and Ports. So instead of `Socket socket = new Socket(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);` I want something along the lines `Socket socket = new Socket(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT || SERVERIP2, SERVERPORT2);` but the problem here is that the operator `||` cannot be applied to int, java.lang.string.

Is there an alternative to get the button to connect to a static IP and Port while using `SERVERIP, SERVERPORT` ?

Comment: Well, you could always just try to connect to an ip and if it doesn't work try the next one. `||` is a _boolean_ operator so this won't work in any case.

Comment: You cannot have two connections from one socket, you would need two sockets or connect to the two IPs one after the other as Thomas suggested.

Comment: If you want to connect to different server, create instance of that socket (client1, client2). Example Socket client1 = new Socket(ServerIP1, Port1); Socket client2 = new Socket(ServerIP2, Port2);

Comment: If you use gsm modem as internet, ip address will be dynamic (public ip address will changed after phone restart). Use internet cable in server side for get static ip address from ISP (internet service provider).

Comment: `I want to make a dedicated button that lets u connect to the IP and Port of the RPi instantly instead of manually writing them down.` You have not at all explained why that is not possible. Of course you can make such a butoon ... if you know the ip... You should have started to tell us why you dont know the ip of the raspi. `String SERVERIP2 = "196.168.43.85";` It looks as if you made a hotspot from your Android device and the raspi is connected to it. Why didnt you tell?

Comment: @blackapps thats an old version of the IP which was used with a hotspot, the IP's at the moment are the same, along the lines 10.1.etc.etc. I know that I am able to connect such a button, my question was, how do I link said button to "SERVERIP2". The value that I gave is never used since I only have one socket active

Comment: Socket socket = new Socket(SERVERIP2, ..... is all you have to do. And you still did not tell why you wanted that or needed that. Al that you want is connect your Antdroid app with a server on a raspi isnt it? And the raspi has a different ip the next day?

Comment: @blackapps but how do I link the new socket to a button that doesn't validate the IP and port first, like "//once clicked connect to IP and Port written in main activity class.", what Im having problems with is making sense on what to write in the loginscreen code to tell him that upon clicking the button it should use the `SERVERIP2` and `SERVERPORT2`. Like for my first socket I use a gettext function that validates the ip upon clicking the connect the button, but I cant use the same way for this button. I need to do that cause, like I said, I just need a button that immediately connects.

Comment: @blackapps the RPi doesnt have another IP the next day, I just need a button that connects automatically to a static IP and a button that lets u write ur IP and port manually. They can use the same IP or can be different IP's they should not be IP restricted, besides the automatic one since that should only connect to 1 given IP and port.

Comment: You can make ten buttons whith ten sockets that connect to ten ip's. I do not understand why that would be a problem.

Comment: @blackapps thats not the problem. My question this whole time was, what line of code equals `once u click on this button connect to the ip given in the main class`

Comment: @blackapps if u can write me a small sophisticated line of code where u make a 2nd socket for the static IP and let the said `taptoconnect` button in the loginscreen activity connect to the ip given in the mainactivity class, I can mark ur aswer as the one that solved my problem

Comment: @blackapps I have not explained why that is not possible because I don't know how to make it, hence why I asked. I'm rather new to this whole coding in android

Comment: Where and how are you starting `ClientAsyncTas()` ? Put the code in your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: Why are you posting code for a login activity? The only thing you do is starting the main activity without using any data from the login activity.

Comment: @blackapps ah man it is what it is never mind, I'm done with it